# how to configure k8s autoscaling?

Tags: kubernetes

How should I configure it to proceed with automatic scale when the average cpu 20% of the pod is over? If the limited pod amount of nodes is exceeded when auto-scaling, how do I expand the nodes horizontally? Is there a way to automatically expand the pod without specifying max and min?

Comment: What attempts have you made to discover a solution to this on your own? What have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Comment: I tried to expand through the CPU without specifying maxReplicas, but I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score -1):

You need to deploy a [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) and configure a [horizontal pod autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) for your workload.